# Inline element and float not behaving as expected

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I'm trying to thoroughly understand browser behavior and at the moment specifically floats.

With the following simple code I would expect the div to float to the left of the text:

```
<span>Some span (inline) text</span>
<div class='a'>Floated div</div>​
```

with the following css:

```
div.a {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

On most browsers it does what I expect, but on IE7, the span text appears on one line, the floated div on the next - see the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtYYZ/

Can someone please explain what is going on in terms of browser layout? My understanding was that "Floated elements are taken out of the normal flow and placed to the left or right". I would have thought nothing would have taken the normal flow from the end of the first line, so the float should stay on that line, as most browsers do. What is the logic behind the IE behavior?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, IE 7 is only 1% of the browser share.

To handle this I would put the follwing in your body element.

```
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. 
 Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a   
href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a>
 to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
```

No need to be encouraging IE 7 use.